# How do I avoid repeating the range selector buttons in plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a subplot that uses a range selector.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Measure)), row = 1, col = 1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(dfsecond.Date), y=list(dfsecond.Measure)), row = 2, col = 2)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

The range selector buttons show up twice. They show up once in the first row and again in the second row. I want the range selector to show up just one time in the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I did for my project and it has time period buttons for stock charts and I edited your code to look just like mine and this worked for me with 3 rows of charts below my main chart, which is where the buttons are. Here is the code:

```py
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        rangeselector_visible = True,
        rangeselector = dict(
            buttons = list([
                dict(
                    count = 1,
                    label = "1m",
                    step = "month",
                    stepmode = "backward"
                )
            ]),
        )
    )
)
```